# Why is the irreducibility of $x^3+3x+1 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ a consequence of its irreducibility in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm reading some lecture notes that argue that $P(x) = x^3+3x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ by first noting that it's irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$. I'm not sure I quite understand this reasoning.

I guess that we can argue roughly like so:

- $P(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$
- Since $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ is a UFD, this means it's prime
- So the ideal it generates is prime
- So the pre-image of this ideal under the quotient map is prime
- **Somehow** use this to establish the primeness of $P(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.
- Deduce its irreducibility in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

**However:**

1. I'm not sure about the "somehow" line, and:
2. There's probably a better way of thinking about it.

> **Question.** Is there a better way of thinking about this? What's really going on here?

Comment: Easier: Reducibility in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ implies reducibility in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$.

Comment: Refer Gallian's contemporary Abstract Algebra where in page 314 he proves the following theorem: Let $p$ be a prime and suppose that $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $\text{deg}(f(x))\geq 1$. Let $\bar{f}(x)$ be the polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}[x]$ obtained by reducing coeffiecients $\pmod{p}$. If $\bar{f}(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_{p}[x]$, and $\text{deg}(f(x))=\text{deg}\,\bar{f}(x)$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the fact that $P$ is monic and of degree$~3$. The degree implies that the only way of being reducible is having a factor of degree$~1$, hence a rational root. Being monic, the rational root must be integer (and it divides the constant coefficient$~1$; be careful to avoid concluding irreducibility even before having had the chance to reduce modulo$~2$); the factor $X-a$ that comes with an integer root$~a$ leads to a similar factor after reduction modulo$~2$, contradicting irreducibility there.

More generally, using just that $P$ has integer coefficients (which is prerequisite to the reduction modulo the prime number $p=2$ being meaningful) and leading coefficient not divisible by$~p$, one can argue as follows. If $P$ were reducible over$~\Bbb Q$, it would be reducible over$~\Bbb Z$ (by the contrapositive of [Gauss' lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)), second formulation) into non-constant polynomials with leading coefficients not divisible by$~p$, which after reduction modulo$~p$ imply that the reduction of $P$ modulo$~p$ factors into factors of the same degrees, hence non-constant, contradicting irreducibility there.

Answer (score 1):

Gauss's lemma proves that if $f\in\Bbb Z[X]$ has no nontrivial factors
in $\Bbb Z[X]$ then it has no nontrivial factors in $\Bbb Q[X]$. But a
nontrivial factorisation of $f$ over $\Bbb Z$ yields one over $\Bbb F_2$.
So if $f$ is irreducible over $\Bbb F_2$, it is irreducible over $\Bbb Z$
and so over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: This post isn't quite true as stated. For example, $3x$ and $2x^2 + x$ both have nontrivial factorizations over $\mathbb{Z}$, but not over $\mathbb{F}_2$. (and, incidentally, one of these is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and the other is not)